# Get filename from NSURLSession download

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I'm using NSURLSession to download file. Some websites (like Amazon) don't use filenames in URL (like: http://server/file.php?id=22). How can I get that filenames?

Example URL without name: [https://odesk-prod-att.s3.amazonaws.com/...oCtjM%3D](https://odesk-prod-att.s3.amazonaws.com/Assignments%3A206911794%3AAttachedDocument?x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzEO7%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEa4AM6010PVN9XHEdD9R%2FGJaGbSpZzAYifHENXX6IBF7RABkd1G79etvJtrPuyHlKb8AS1n5YNAlh6a4fr7OkiMLsxryKvNpcYWB1znHeJpBxv9jDcMmvuXOzMh9xCEkGk8dDcNeY8pvnLIbxH1eB%2B4f2FsoHejwZYrT28B8dzD6JSkGOoV0SJ17SC1beXSwK02UgGBL50wHxnbBTkiQv58ED4jabWa%2BoospRupYj47NwFnENCVBzmNuiIrwtUnCD8L0AbLDZXHZWK5M7cPR0wf5hDL6STEZ2zS4IWrIhWCaBA5VguKBm6Pf09waO5XRQWM5chO6GcBpE%2FpSWuJ%2B3ouJnr7J6ZLjTvYVIXxXX%2Fo0w5XAaW00Ap%2BLgn5ANrdC9X2rJroijIj403bPm%2FSiJYPSQff4OIGcJQiaFTx1%2FroZqrFQ7x8%2B51%2BNScUjIuUy2ix6oazsaMlW1HOAnjsD9Vn53gd9nphLabAPtvyc4YKZen3xD6NB6wzeLlsyKM1Nu%2FcJZsb064hLlq%2FjXOD6FNkC71FSxp9jN%2FykkEMZvxnA%2BBf55%2BPcY7YCLObAvQJ2ilslAJb8jxKMSZ%2BOzO7Nnte9f3W3%2FyqL%2BGHHmRegpJj71nyzQqAgKCZk2yBKEayXlKHe0gmu%2FstQU%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAIREB3VFJ3IA4SBXA&Expires=1455117478&Signature=UfZx2Rw0RsZYRGZhy3xo3%2BoCtjM%3D)

I'm using such function:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
    print("Download finished: \(location.absoluteString)")
}

// Download finished: file:///.../CFNetworkDownload_UTywas.tmp
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check for the suggested filename before creating your own:

```
downloadTask.response?.suggestedFilename
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally found semi-solution for that. Now I'm detecting MIME of file and renaming it according MIME type.

Was: "abcd.tmp"
New: "your_prefix.png"

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
    guard let mimeType = downloadTask.response?.MIMEType,
        let fileExtension = mimeTypeToExtension(mimeType) else {
        return
    }

    // Your file name is: "prefixYouWant.\(fileExtension)"
}

/// Converting MIME Type to extension (e.g.: jpg)
func mimeTypeToExtension(mimeType: String) -> String? {
    let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mimeType, nil)
    guard let fileUTI = uti?.takeRetainedValue(),
        let fileExtension = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(fileUTI, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension) else { return nil }

    let extensionString = String(fileExtension.takeRetainedValue())
    return extensionString
}
```

> Dont forget to `import MobileCoreServices`